# Define `copy` for `trait`

Tags: scala

Given:

```
sealed trait X { val x: String }
case class A(x: String) extends X
case class B(x: String) extends X
```

I defined a `copy` method at the `X` trait:

```
def copy(x: X, newValue: String): X = x match {
  case A(_) => A(newValue)
  case B(_) => B(newValue)
}
```

However, I thought that I could do better, i.e be precise.

Because, technically, just because an `A` is input, a `B` could be output since a `B` is a sub-class of `X`.

So I tried:

```
def copyBetter[T <: X](x: T, newValue: String): T = x match {
 case A(_) => A(newValue)
 case B(_) => B(newValue)
}
```

But, I got compile-time errors:

```
<console>:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A
 required: T
          case A(_) => A(newValue)
                        ^
<console>:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : B
 required: T
          case B(_) => B(newValue)
                        ^
```

How can I implement `copyBetter` with the given signature?

Comment: I think I had a similar issue and I solved it returning `X`, the problem here is that your return type is dynamical and you cannot figure out which type `T` is gonna be before the invocation, it's a bit different from a normal call to a generic method, in that case you can specify the type beforehand because you know what's gonna be returned, here you can't.

Comment: I'd take a look at shapeless, just to check if your problem might correspond to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to implement a method with this signature (ignoring `null`) is `def copyBetter[T <: X](x: T, newValue: String): T = x`! Why? Because singleton types exist. Given this signature, the following must compile, since `x.type` is a subtype of `X`:

```
val x = A(1)
val y: x.type = copyBetter[x.type](x, 2)
```

`y`'s type says that `y` must be the same object as `x` (or `null`). Because in your implementation it isn't, this implementation doesn't fit the signature.

Comment: `Because singleton types exist` Could you please say more or point me to a link? What's a `singleton type`?

Comment: `x.type` in the example is a singleton type. It's the type with exactly two values: `x` and `null`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

```
def copyBetter[T <: X](x: T, newValue: String): X = x match {
  case A(_) => A(newValue)
  case B(_) => B(newValue)
}
```

Comment: Now, with this working example, `copyBetter`'s could still accept an `A`, but return a `B`. Although the definition would not be rational, I'd argue, it'd compile. Is there no way to get one level higher, i.e. require an input sub-child of `X` and that same type as an output?

Comment: The compiler cannot know which case `x` is going to match at runtime, so it selects the most specific supertype - which is `X`. I don't think there's a way around it.

Comment: Does it actually compile? `_ <: X` is only allowed as a type _argument_ (e.g. `List[_ <: X]`), not as a type itself. I get "Unbound wildcard type": http://scastie.org/21879.

Comment: I removed the check-box since Alexey is right. I just got the same compile-time error: `error: unbound wildcard type`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith edited but agreed, his was the first correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning a `T` but an `X`. `A` and `B` extends `X` but not `T`.

Try with this signature:

```
def copyBetter[T <: X](x: T, newValue: String): X = // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer. I accepted Zoltan's since he answered 1 minute earlier.

Comment: Same as Zoltan's answer: there is absolutely no benefit to using this instead of the original `copy`.

Comment: And there's no benefit since a child of `X` can always be passed where an argument's type is `X`? In other words, the constraint does not add anything else than simply writing `x: X`?

Answer (score 0):

Simple - how do you expect the return type to be `T`, when it is not even involved in the method body. `T` is irrelevant, and the return type is the common ancestor of `A` and `B`.

Also, shouldn't you be defining it as:

```
def copy(newValue: String): X = this match {
  case _: A => A(newValue)
  case _: B => B(newValue)
}
```